# using ifelse statement in code and switch in interface in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to use the ifelse statement to supply conditions to global variable called "space-death?" implemented at the netlogo interface as a switch.

```
    to Pass-Away
     ifelse space-death? [ 
     ask turtles[ Pass-Away-Space ]
     ask turtles[ Pass-Away-Time]
    ]
  ]
end
```

In the code, I implement a turtle mortality procedure called "Pass-Away" which when run, asks if the space-death switch is turned on at the netlogo interface. If the space-death switch is on, then it asks the turtles to call and run another netlogo procedure block called "Pass-Away-Space" and if it not, regular turtle death ensues by calling another procedure block dubbed "Pass-Away-Time."

However, I am getting the following error message:

***IFELSE expected three inputs, a TRUE/FALSE, a command block and a command block***

Can one see where I may have gone wrong and correct this code accordingly. Alternatively, if there is a better code-based way to implement this logic other than an interface global, please indulge me in your response.

Comment: Put `][` between your two `ask` commands.
(Additionally, I recommend moving the `ask turtles` outside of this proc, making it a turtle proc.)

Comment: Thanks @Alan. I moved the ask turtles however now there seem to be problems with my embedded procedure "Pass-Away-Space"  that I am sure there is a quick fix for with your expertise. The error for the following code reads "expected input to be a number but got a list (#s)":   `to Pass-Away-Space
  ;ask turtles [
    let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch] of turtles)
    if chances >= 1 [die
      set dead-count dead-count + 1
    ]
  ;]
end`

Comment: This is getting too hard to discuss in comments.  I'll post illustrative code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
globals [space-death?]

to setup
  ca
  set space-death? true
  crt 100
end

to go
  ask turtles [pass-away]
end

to pass-away
  ifelse space-death? [ 
    Pass-Away-Space
  ][
    Pass-Away-Time
  ]
end

to pass-away-space
  ;your code here
end

to pass-away-time
  ;your code here
end
```